# where clause did not work with WITH

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

where clause did not work with WITH when i wrote  **where Prse ='h'** it shows me an error 'Invalid column'

```
;with cT(FLDID  ,FLD10  ,FLD610)
as
(
select  * from Table556 
inner join Table555 on table555.FLD9=FLD318
where FLD610=150 
)

select case when fld609 <=12 then 'h' else 's' end as Prse,* from cT 
where Prse ='h'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `with` has nothing to do with it. You're only introducing `Prse` in the final `SELECT` clause - and you can't reference such columns from the `WHERE` clause (since `WHERE` logically runs *before* `SELECT`).

Did you want:

```
;with cT(Prse, FLDID  ,FLD10  ,FLD610)
as
(
select case when fld609 <=12 then 'h' else 's' end as Prse, * from Table556 
inner join Table555 on table555.FLD9=FLD318
where FLD610=150 
)

select * from cT 
where Prse ='h'
```

Comment: @Dems - done. Good catch (I don't usually use explicit column lists in my CTEs)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
          FLDID
        , FLD10
        , FLD610
        , Prse = 
            CASE WHEN FLD609 <= 12 
                THEN 'h' 
                ELSE 's' 
            END  
    FROM dbo.Table556 t 
    JOIN dbo.Table555 t2 ON t2.FLD9 = t.FLD318
    WHERE FLD610 = 150 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE Prse = 'h'
```

Comment: Do you *ever* offer any explanation of what you've changed or why? You only ever seem to have "try this one" or some variant and some code, which the person asking the question then has to pore over to determine what you've changed. Of course, there's little learning opportunity for them, since they only discover what you've changed - never *why*.

Comment: @Mir Shakeel Hussain, I am not a Damien. :)